# (Self)update executable jar file which was running update jar method

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have an executable jar file.In that there is a method which interact with the sever and gets updated executable jar file(if any) and replace the current jar file(which was running update jar program). is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, yes, it's a complete pain in the ... code. It might have changed, but even as of Java 8, it was still giving us issues.  Basically what you need to do is, download the Jar to a different location, execute that Jar so it then deletes and replaces the old Jar and the execute the Jar again, in it's new location and remove the downloaded Jar, piece of pie